# CI: Get returned information in ajax response

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am working on a project with CI and Ajax. Since, I'm working with ajax after a long time, I am having some issues in debugging. I have written this code. In which i am sending data to to controller function `login`. Please guide me regarding how to check whether the data is reaching controller, and model. And also on how to return data from model to controller and from controller to view.

My Ajax code is as follows:

```
$('#login').click(function () {
    if (($('#inputUname').val() === "") || ($('#inputPassword').val() === "")) {
        alert('please username and password');
    } else {
        var data = {
            'uname': $('#inputPassword').val(),
            'pwd': $('#inputPassword').val()
        };
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: base_url + "home/login",
            data: data,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response)
            {
                alert('Ajax Success');
            }, error: function () {
                alert('Ajax Error');
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Controller home.php Code is as follows:

```
public function login() {
    $uname = $this->input->post('uname');
    $pwd = $this->input->post('pwd');
    $data['userinfo'] = $this->dis_model->check_user($uname,$pwd);
    return $data;
}
```

and Model Dis_model.php code is as follows:

```
function check_user($uname, $pwd) {
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->where('uname', $uname);
        $this->db->where('pwd', $pwd);
        $query = $this->db->get('users');
        return $query->result();
    }
```

All positive suggestions are welcomed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try to print out $this->input->post('uname') in controller

Comment: Everytime you call a function in a controller using AJAX and declaring datatype as JSON, you MUST print your result encoded in JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Change In Controller:

```
public function login() {
$uname = $this->input->post('uname');
$pwd = $this->input->post('pwd');
$data['userinfo'] = $this->dis_model->check_user($uname,$pwd);
echo $uname;
exit;
}
```

Change in ajax:

```
 $('#login').click(function () {
if (($('#inputUname').val() === "") || ($('#inputPassword').val() === "")) {
    alert('please username and password');
} else {
    var data = {
        'uname': $('#inputPassword').val(),
        'pwd': $('#inputPassword').val()
    };
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: base_url + "home/login",
        data: data,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response)
        {
            alert(response);
        }, error: function () {
            alert('Ajax Error');
        }
    });
}
});
```

Same in modal

Answer (score 0):

Change in Controller

```
public function login() {
   $uname = $this->input->post('uname');
   $pwd = $this->input->post('pwd');
   $data['userinfo'] = $this->dis_model->check_user($uname,$pwd);
   echo json_encode($data['userinfo']);
   die;
}
```

Change in ajax

```
     $('#login').click(function () {
      if (($('#inputUname').val() === "") || ($('#inputPassword').val() === "")) {
        alert('please username and password');
       } else {
 var data = {
    'uname': $('#inputPassword').val(),
    'pwd': $('#inputPassword').val()
};
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: base_url + "home/login",
    data: data,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (response)
     {
         alert(response);
     }, error: function () {
         alert('Ajax Error');
     }
  });
  }
});
```